# Where does the extra 5px come from in this fiddle?

Tags: html, css

I created this seemingly simple fiddle and found that the containing div has a y dimension that is 5px more than what I would expect.

I don't want to fix the 5px, I want to understand where it is coming from.  I checked the inspector and there is 0 margin and padding for both the icons and the containing div.

http://jsfiddle.net/dy3qhv0L/

```
<style>
#icon_holder{
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.icon{
  border: 1px dotted #ffffff;  
}
</style>
<div id='icon_holder'>
  <img class='icon' src='http://www.arcmarks.com/web/images/icon_facebook.png'>
  <img class='icon' src='http://www.arcmarks.com/web/images/icon_google.png'>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but browsers render text (and inline images) with gaps (like letter and line spacing).  You can remove this by setting the font size to 0 on the parent div.

Comment: @box - that is the fix, which I'll take as an answer if you want it, but why does font-size effect my div when there is no text in it!  What madness is this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dy3qhv0L/2/)**

The space is there **because image is an inline element by default**, If you use **block** and for aligning in same line you can use **float as left**, you can get expected result.

```
#icon_holder {
    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.icon {
    border: 1px dotted #ffffff;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

For more info, Refer this **[link](http://loopj.com/2008/06/16/removing-gaps-under-images-in-css/)**

Comment: the answer is in the comment above, this was just a matter of having additional browser resets.

Answer (score 0):

These element are inline-block - so they flow with text and are positioned on baseline, extra pixels are from line height.

To fix that add float:left style in icon class.
You have to add clear element after that - simplest css:

```
#icon_holder {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#icon_holder:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.icon{
    border: 1px dotted #ffffff;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: but why 5px, where does this number come from?

Comment: The question was about the y dimension, not the x dimension!

Comment: corrected my answer - thank for pointing out my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

The icon displays as inline element. set `vertical-align:top;`

**CSS**

```
.icon{
 border: 1px dotted #ffffff; 
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: but why 5px, where does this number come from?

Comment: @cadegalt - It comes from applying the font-size property to the font's metrics. Use a different font and you can get different spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You should add -

```
<div id="icon_holder">
  <img class="icon" src="http://www.arcmarks.com/web/images/icon_facebook.png"><!--
  --><img class="icon" src="http://www.arcmarks.com/web/images/icon_google.png">
</div>
```

and in css -

```
.icon {
    border:1px dotted #ffffff
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uss css it will solve issue

```
.icon {
    border: 1px dotted #ffffff;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question